# Change detection on ngFor

Tags: angular

I have 2 select elements in the DOM. Options for the second one should be populated depending on my selection on first select element. I have created simplified version of it here: https://plnkr.co/edit/tJMjCFp3hQ4PnrGWn3qG?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <select (change)="setResults($event)">
        <option value='numbers'>Numbers</option>
        <option value='colors'>Colors</option>
      </select>
      <select>
        <option *ngFor = "let op of results" value={{op}}>{{op}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {

  }

  public value: string;
  public result: any[];
  public colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
  public numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  public setResults(e){
    let name = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log(name);
    if(name === 'numbers'){
      this.result = this.numbers;
      console.log(this.result);
    }
    else
      this.result = this.colors;
  }

}
```

It is not working right now. Any suggestions on what is wrong?

Comment: Use `result` instead of `results` in view because all your code means that it is the right variable :)

Comment: What @yurzui said. https://plnkr.co/edit/6cs0JJm3XEYE6eD9mPCr?p=preview